# Folder's "system" attribute disappears after copying to USB drive

Tags: windows, usb, file-attributes, desktop.ini

I have a "Desktop.ini" file in a specific folder. I define the folder as a system folder using

```
cmd : attrib +s folder
```

and everything works well. But when I copy the folder to a USB drive, my folder losses its "system" attribute. How can I keep the attribute when copying the folder? (I need the "Desktop.ini" file to work everywhere)

Comment: What is the USB formatted as?

Comment: @harrymc - FAT32

Comment: What is the copy method? Just `copy`?

Comment: Is there any specific way to copy ??!! By the way it doesn't matter because I need it working for everyone who has my folder , and it means it may be copied many times

Comment: There are many utilities: copy, robocpy, Explorer copy and other utilities. But most will not copy System folders, and Explorer will not even show it. So what did you do?

Comment: I simply copied.